# Problems with MS Forefront and jira-python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jira, python-jira

I'm trying to execute the next code:

```
    import jira.client
from jira.client import JIRA

'''
Connect to JIRA. Return None on error
'''
try:
    options = {'server': 'https://myjira.es', 'verify':False}
    jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('myuser', 'mypass'))
    print jira 
    print "OK"
except Exception,e:
    print"Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e
    print "Error"

issue = jira.issue('jira-10')
print issue
```

And I received an 403 error with he last print ('issue'), the first connection goes OK and I think that could be a problem with MS Forefront previous validation.

Any help would be appreciated.